# Using VB.NET and C# in the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, interop

My organization has previously written software in VB.NET. We decided to do some enhancements upon it and were wondering whether we can write the new enhancements in C#? Can VB.NET projects live side-by-side with C# projects?

What about performance?

Are there any other issues?

Comment: I disagree with the edit that was made, the meaning was far clearer before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VB.NET project can interface perfectly fine with one written in C# as they are both compiled to MSIL. There shouldn't be any performance impacts.

The main issue you would have to deal with is your solution is going to get more complicated if it contains multiple languages. Plus developers will need to have knowledge of both VB.NET and C#, in general *C# developers get grumpy when they are forced to work in VB.NET* ;)

On the flip-side, there are far more C# developers than VB.NET developers.

Comment: +1. For complete sack: all MS .Net assemblies are compiled to MSIL and there is a slight performance advantage of C# over VB.Net but not humanly noticeable.

Comment: +1. I agree! Several years ago some companies were still coding their projects using VB.NET ignoring C#. For them learning another language is very expensive and time consuming now that VB.NET is dying those companies are convinced to migrate to C#. The best example of migration for me is the .NET Nuke CMS. Before it was written in VB.NET now it's C#.

Comment: @Jobert ". . . now that VB.NET is dying . ." [citation needed]